# Generate url with api_key and slug with Tastypie (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, tastypie, django-urls

I want to generate a url for a slug consisting of http://localhost:8000/api/v1/ generated with Tastypie url pattern + api_key generated for a user with Tastypies ApiKey + generated slug with Slugify from a title field. I want to match   http://localhost:8000/api/v1/api_key/slug (see url - section). I'm not sure how to connect the views-function with the ModelResource class SlugResource in api.py and define the url. Any help is greatly appreciated.

In models I've added methods for generating a new slug object for each new object in the title field in the function save() and get_absolute_url() that returns the field slug (self.slug) as link with models.permalink - decorator and a name to use in the urls, slug_.

```
in models.py 
class Myclass(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            # Newly created object, so set slug
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)

            super(Myclass, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return 'slug_', (self.slug,)
```

In views I've extracted a slug from the titlefield from the form SlugForm and api_key for the current authenticated user.

```
from tastypie.models import ApiKey
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

in views.py 
one_slugpost(request, postID, slug):
    one_session = Myclass.objects.get(id=postID)
    one_slug = Myclass.objects.get(slug=slug)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SlugForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
          # get title  
          title = request.POST["title"]
          # create a slug of title
          slug = slugify(title)
          # get the username for the current authenticated user
          user = request.user
          # get the user id
          user_id = user.id
          # get or generate a new api key with Tastypie ApiKey for user with id user_id
          api_key = ApiKey.objects.get_or_create(user=user_id)[0].key

   else:
        form = SlugForm()

    c = {"one_one_session":one_one_session,"one_slug":slug,"form":form}
    c.update(csrf(request))

    template = 'test_index.html'
    return render_to_response(template, c,context_instance=RequestContext(request)) 

in api.py
from myapp.models import Myclass

# ModelResource draws all resource (content) from a class, in this case Myclass
# and makes it a webbservice-resource
class SlugResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        # provide  webbservice-resource features to all instances of  Myclass
        queryset = Myclass.objects.all()
        # the name of the resource, same as for url- patterns
        # e.g api/v1/
        resource_name = "slug_resource"
```

In urls, the pattern for http://localhost:8000/api/v1/ works with Api but not the url test for postid and slug which I want to extend the api - url pattern http://localhost:8000/api/v1/ with.

```
in urls.py 
# get api for urls from Tastypie - webbservice class SlugResource
# and set api_name to v1 
from tastypie.api import Api
from myapp.api import SlugResource
v1_api = Api(api_name = 'v1')
v1_api.register(SlugResource())

urlpatterns = patterns('',



 # include all api instance urls in SlugResource in myapp api.py model

   url(r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls)),

 # define url matching postid and slug- not working
 # here's where I want to match ...localhost/api/v1/api_key/slug

 url(r'^test(?P<postID>\d+)/(?P<slug>\w+)/$',one_slugpost, name='slug_'),
```

Comment: I don't understand what is you want to accomplish

Comment: I have created a url http://localhost:8000/api/v1/ in api.py resource - class and I want to add a slug, the "title"field converted to a slug with slugify, for instance if the user submits title "my article"  it's converted to slug "my-article". I want to add the slug to the url path in the tastypieclass or extend it in the urls so it becomes, matches "http://  localhost:8000/api/v1/my-article(slug)"

Comment: For the first part you can override django's model `save` method. For the second part, don't you mean `/api/v1/articles/my-slugged-article`?

Comment: In the model class Myclass () in the code I have a method that saves/overrides the field slug with strings in the field title with slugify, so it automatically generates my-slugged-article if  the user adds "my slugged article" as a string in the field "title". I want to add a url that can match the slug, for instance http.../api/v1/articles/my-slugged-article (with var slug), similar to adding pattern http.../api/v1/articles/slug_resource=Dave which would match slug as Dave  .....

Comment: but I'm not sure of how to add a slug in the SlugResource() class so that /api/v1/articles/slug_resource=slug would take any slug defined and saved in the model Myclass().

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use `prepend_urls`. Something like this should do it:

```
class ArticleResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = MyClass.objects.all()
        detail_uri_name = 'slug'

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<slug>[\w\d_.-]+)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name="api_dispatch_detail"),
        ]
```